# Bokeh Hovertool Data from Separate Columns

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am displaying a 100% stacked bar chart in Bokeh to show the percentage of a category, here (A,B). The categories A,B... will represent the top x categories of a dataset so their categories will not be the same for each row. One row could be cats, dogs. The next could be from cats, birds. So I have another set of columns [A_label]... to display those categories. The hovertool currently displays the column name and value i.e. [A_perc : 0.500]. But I would like it to display the label and the actual value, [cats: 1]. Is there a way to accomplish this with the hovertool?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.palettes import magma
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'entries' : ['0','1','2','3'],
        'A_perc' : [1,0.5,0.2,0],
        'B_perc' : [0,0.5,0.8,1],
        'A_vals' : [2,1,2,0],
        'B_vals' : [0,1,8,1],
        'A_label' : ['cats', 'dogs', 'birds', 'cows'],
        'B_label' : ['dogs', 'birds', 'mice', 'deer']
    }
)

p = figure(
    x_range=['0','1','2','3'], 
    plot_height=400, 
    plot_width=650, 
    toolbar_location=None, 
    background_fill_alpha=0.0,
    background_fill_color = None,
    border_fill_color = None,
    outline_line_color = None,
    tools="hover", 
    tooltips="$name: @$name"
)

colors = magma(2)
p.vbar_stack(
    ['A_perc','B_perc'], 
    x='entries', 
    width=0.9, 
    color=colors, 
    source=data, 
    legend_label=['A_perc','B_perc'], 
)

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a custom hovertool.
Just replace one line in the definition of the figure.

```
# tooltips="$name: @$name" 
tooltips=TOOLTIPS
```

and add some HTML right befor the definition of the fiugre.

```
TOOLTIPS = """
    <div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #05ABFF;">@A_label:</span>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #000;">@A_vals</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #05ABFF;">@B_label:</span>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #000;">@B_vals</span>
        </div>
    </div>
"""
```

Make sure you are using the (correct) column names which are given with the source inside the `div`-tags.

Comment:
This solutions shows always both absolut values (A and B). So the tooltip has always two entries.

To get further information read the [documentation about tooltips](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#basic-tooltips).

**Complete Example**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.palettes import magma
import pandas as pd
output_notebook()

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'entries' : ['0','1','2','3'],
        'A_perc' : [1,0.5,0.2,0],
        'B_perc' : [0,0.5,0.8,1],
        'A_vals' : [2,1,2,0],
        'B_vals' : [0,1,8,1],
        'A_label' : ['cats', 'dogs', 'birds', 'cows'],
        'B_label' : ['dogs', 'birds', 'mice', 'deer']
    }
)

TOOLTIPS = """
    <div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #05ABFF;">@A_label:</span>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #000;">@A_vals</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #05ABFF;">@B_label:</span>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #000;">@B_vals</span>
        </div>
    </div>
"""

p = figure(
    x_range=['0','1','2','3'], 
    plot_height=400, 
    plot_width=650, 
    toolbar_location=None, 
    background_fill_alpha=0.0,
    background_fill_color = None,
    border_fill_color = None,
    outline_line_color = None,
    tooltips=TOOLTIPS,
)

colors = magma(2)
p.vbar_stack(
    ['A_perc','B_perc'], 
    x='entries', 
    width=0.9, 
    color=colors, 
    source=data, 
    legend_label=['A_perc','B_perc'], 
)

show(p)
```

**Output**
[image: Output in a Jupyter Notebook]